# Go Gorm raw sql create table then insert error

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I got encountered some problem with Go and Gorm package. I was trying to create table and insert table using raw query. Sadly, the error said I got a syntax error in the SQL code, but when I try to execute it by using PhpMyAdmin it's just working fine.

Here is the code minimum reproduce code:

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

const CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`a` int); INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`) VALUES (1);"

func main() {
    dsn := "sandbox:sandbox@tcp(localhost)/sandbox?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err2 := db.Exec(CREATE_TABLE_SQL).Error
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's producing the error below:

```
$ go run .

2023/03/09 13:54:01 go-raw-sql-create-table-error/main.go:17 Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`) VALUES (1)' at line 1       
[0.524ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`a` int); INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`) VALUES (1);
panic: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`) VALUES (1)' at line 1

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        go-raw-sql-create-table-error/main.go:19 +0xef
exit status 2
```

I'm currently using Docker running MySQL container for dev.
Here is the Docker compose that I'm using:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sandboxroot
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sandbox
      MYSQL_USER: sandbox
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: sandbox
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: sandbox
      PMA_PASSWORD: sandbox
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Comment: Split the query into two and execute them separately.

Comment: hi @mkopriva, unfortunately. this code is for minimum reproducing. the variable inside Exec() method may be a string that comes from the file read of the SQL dump file.

Comment: Can't check right now, but the backticks look suspicious to me. Could it be you have to change that to single quotes? ( ' )

Comment: I tried changing backticks to single quotes as you suggested and executed it in PhpMyAdmin but it seems to have more errors. so I switched back to the original one as I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection string you should add parameter `multiStatements=true`

So your code would look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

const CREATE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`a` int); INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`) VALUES (1);"

func main() {
    dsn := "sandbox:sandbox@tcp(localhost)/sandbox?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local&multiStatements=true"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err2 := db.Exec(CREATE_TABLE_SQL).Error
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
}
```